# Login functions

Tags: functions, login

Where are the functions that handle logging the user in? Specifically, the one that checks the users plain text password at the login page against the hashed formatted one stored in the database?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/7e3f0cf45e59b77927fd7111d613eec2a621db45/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L2007

Answer (score 0):

Some of the functions are in [`wp-includes/pluggable.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php), notably `wp_authenticate()` though you'll notice that most of the work is done by filters hooked to `authenticate`. The names of those you can find in [`wp-includes/default-filters.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L314) and the function definitions in [`wp-includes/user.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/user.php#L0).

But be aware that functions in `pluggables.php` can be replaced by theme or plugin code in their entirety and functions hooked to `authenticate` can be removed and replaced as well as altered via the numerous hooks provided by the various functions.